# Many to one association converting to postres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am in the process of converting a rails app form sqlite to postgres so that I can deploy with heroku.  I have postgres installed and I ran migrations, however when I try to run a query to find all the housemates associated with a house I get the following error

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying = integer
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "mates"  WHERE "mates"."house_id" = 1
                                                           ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "mates"  WHERE "mates"."house_id" = 1
```

This error originates form a sign-up view that you are redirected to to create and administrator after adding a house.  Here is the view code:

```
Extracted source (around line #4):

1: <div class="container">
2:  <div class="row">
3:      <div class="span5 offset3">
4:          <% if current_house.mates.empty? %>
5:              <h2>Add an Administrator</h2>
6:          <% else %>
7:              <h2>Add a New Housemate</h2>
```

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting existing rails app to postres from sqlite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17643326/converting-existing-rails-app-to-postres-from-sqlite)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `add_house_id_to_mates` migration and change line 3 from string to  integer.
After this, remove the `20130628212206_change_type_of_house_id_in_house.rb` migration.

Run migrations from zero:

`rake db:drop db:create db:migrate`

Comment: 20130628212206_change_type_of_house_id_in_house.rb ?

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the house_id column in the table mates as a character type, and it should be an integer. Some RDBMS are forgiving of this, but PostgreSQL is not.

You should correct this with a migration, and check the database schema for other such errors as well.

Because it's possible for a character column to contain non-numeric values, when migrating you'll have to issue the SQL statement:

```
alter table  mates
alter column house_id
type integer using cast(house_id as integer);
```

Comment: When I run a the migration `change_column :mates, :house_id, :integer` I get the following error:`PG::Error: ERROR:  column "house_id" cannot be cast automatically to type integer
HINT:  Specify a USING expression to perform the conversion.`